# Cannot go back through an image Array

Tags: javascript, function

I have been spending an entire day on this and need it done by tomorrow so I doubt I will get any sleep tonight but if anyone can solve this issue I would be so very grateful as it is driving me mad.

I have tried many methods but this is the code: http://www.mediafire.com/download/xibb998x4yg5avc/Image_JavaScript_Array_help!.zip

And this is a picture of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efqjp.jpg

Basically I have a table of images:

```
<td><a href="#zoomedIn"><img id="0" onclick="showLarge(this);" src="Media//Gallery//img_1.png" alt="Gallery Image 1" /></a></td>
<td><a href="#zoomedIn"><img id="1" onclick="showLarge(this);" src="Media//Gallery//img_2.png" alt="Gallery Image 2" /></a></td>
<td><a href="#zoomedIn"><img id="2" onclick="showLarge(this);" src="Media//Gallery//img_3.png" alt="Gallery Image 3" /></a></td>
<td><a href="#zoomedIn"><img id="3" onclick="showLarge(this);" src="Media//Gallery//img_4.png" alt="Gallery Image 4" /></a></td>
<td><a href="#zoomedIn"><img id="4" onclick="showLarge(this);" src="Media//Gallery//img_5.png" alt="Gallery Image 5" /></a></td>
```

And the "showLarge(this); event handler will call this function:

```
function showLarge(img) {
    var largeFrame = document.getElementById("zoomedIn");
    largeFrame.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var largeImage = document.getElementById("largeImage");
    largeImage.src = img.src;
    findIndex(img.src);
}

function findIndex(src) {
    for (var i = 0; i = imgArray.length; i++)
        if (imgArray[i].src == src) {
          currentImage = i;
        }
}
```

This is used so that when you click one of the smaller images, as shown in the background on the picture, it will open up a frame and give the large image frame the small images source so the small image appears much larger.

However the part that does NOT work is that there are two buttons: one being the next button and another the previous button. I have tried two methods: The "changeImage(direction)" which never seems to work and this one:

```
 function nextImage(event) {
        var img = document.getElementById("largeImage");

        for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
        {
            if(imgArray[i].src == img.src)
            {
                if(i === imgArray.length){
                    img.src = imgArray[0].src;
                    break;
                }
                img.src = imgArray[i+1].src;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The second one allows me to use the next button but if I try to reverse it for the previous button then it does not work. I just want to be able to click through the images and then hide the image and click on another and it will work the exact same. I recommend downloading the code and trying it out for yourself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First off, if this is for a class and you have to do it this way, fine but you really should be using [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).
I recommend taking the approach that once the image is clicked, you use its ID (since you've ID'd all the images) and use that number to cycle through the images. Rather than using next/back, simply call a "changeImage()" method and pass it the ID of the image you want to switch to. That's the fastest way to fix this. So:

1) Give all those slideshow images a class, like "slideshowImage".

2) Use javascript to dynamically assign them all an onclick function: "changeImage()".

3) Inside changeImage() use the clicked image's ID to to open an image. You can reuse changeImage() for the next step.

4) In the event that changeImage() is not run due to a click on an image element (e.g. the slideshow is already open and you've clicked next/previous), increment or decrement the previously clicked ID number and re-run the function to change the image.

Hope that helps (don't have the time to give you a code snippit right now... but this should point you in the right direction). Plus, using unotrusive JS is much cleaner, and is, more importantly, absolute industry standard.

Comment: Thank you. I have been working on the changeImage() for around 8 hours today already and gave up. I am not sure if I can do it. Will have to try tomorrow possibly. Will keep trying though for another 10 hours or so lol